# Addition, multiplication, exponentiation... What is next function of this series?

Tags: functions, terminology

Addition can be (informally) defined as the application of successor function $S$ on $a$ $b$ times, i.e. $a+b=S\stackrel{b}{\cdots}S a$. Multiplication can be defined as the addition of $a$ with itself $b$ times, i.e. $a\times b=a+\stackrel{b}{\cdots}+a$. Exponentiation can be defined as the multiplication of $a$ with itself $b$ times, i.e. $a\wedge b=a\times\stackrel{b}{\cdots}\times a$.

Intuitively, someone can go one step through this succession and define a function that applies exponentiation of $a$ with itself $b$ times, i.e. $a\star b=a\wedge\stackrel{b}{\cdots}\wedge a$, and repeat this step again and again obtaining an infinite series of functions.

Does this series have a name (at least its fourth element, the next following exponentiation)?

Comment: After exponentiation is [tetration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration), followed by [pentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentation).

Comment: Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation  for a general overview. (This page also has a list of named hyperoperations, and I was disappointed to learn that after pentation comes hexation, not sexation.)

Comment: In addition the the hyperoperation reference above, see, in particular, the page on the Knuth up-arrow: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730233).