# Definition of tetration

Tags: definition, intuition, tetration, hyperoperation

We all know that many years ago we invented powers. e.g. $3^4$ meant how many times we multiply 3. i.e. $3^4=3\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdot 3$. 
But then, people started asking questions like what is the meaning of $3^{-4}$, or $3^{\frac{1}{4}}$ and so forth. Same goes for factorial. People wanted to determine what is the meaning of $2.3!$ or $-\pi !$, and so forth. 
By the same logic, I started wondering what can be the meaning of $^{\frac{1}{2}}2$, or $^{-3}4$, or even $^i3$, and could not come up with an answer, or something close to one. 
Does someone have an idea that can be used to determine what $^{-3}4$ would be?

**EDIT:** Note that I read about the subject on Wikipedia, and this stackexchange question: [How would tetration work for non integer numbers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1864661/how-would-tetration-work-for-non-integer-numbers). I wanted to see if someone else had an idea.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Extensions.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1864661/how-would-tetration-work-for-non-integer-numbers

Comment: There seems to be no solution for such problems (yet), especially involving $i$. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280251/what-is-i-exponentiated-to-itself-i-times).

Comment: It does not, I also wrote it in the EDIT @MatthewTowers. Do you see it now?